# How do I access my e-mail account?

Tags: gmail

When I open Gmail it defaults back to the account of the previous person who used the laptop.

How do I get to mine from there?

Answer (score 3):

As @pnuts suggested, you'll need to log them out in order for you to sign in. Look in the top right corner for their avatar or user icon, or the *Settings* menu.  Click on that, and when the drop-down menu appears, select **Log Out** or **Sign Out**.  Then you'll be able to log in as yourself.

Make sure that once you have finished using Gmail, you log yourself out, using the same steps above, rather than just closing the tab or window.